# NServiceBus F5 load balancing Subscribers without using a distributor

Tags: c#, load-balancing, nservicebus, nservicebus-distributor

We are looking to use our F5's to load balance MSMQ messages without using a distributor (our windows boxes are not currently clustered).

Using DB subscription storage & publishing to a VIP, would 3 subscribers register with the publisher? (ie the VIP, & both subscribers?)

Using MSMQ transactional queues will 1 subscriber only process the message?  As we only want to publish to the VIP would 1 server process the message & would the callback to the originating server succeed?

Thanks

Comment: Each subscriber would get a copy of the message.  Why not use the distribution mechanism?

Comment: Main reasons taken from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515136/nservicebus-pros-and-cons-of-using-nservicebus-distributor

Comment: Also I only want 1 of the subscribers to process the message - they will be identical machines

Comment: Ah, I see.  So F5 is a product of some kind :) --- does it read a msmq queue and then balance it itself?  If that is the case then you probably do not want to `publish` but rather `send` to the endpoint queue.  Callbacks will need to be tested but I cannot see why it wouldn't work since the processing endpoint communicates with the receiver directly.

Answer (score 3):

MSMQ doesn't work with transactional messages behind a load balancer:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/03/19/load-balancing-msmq-a-brief-discussion.aspx

Comment: Marked as correct but the article states 'Transactional messaging doesn't work because acknowledgements cannot be returned to the sending machine as it's IP address has been masked by that of the NLB device'    In the case of the F5 load balancer the original machines IP address can be forwarded in the routing rules, thus the acknowledgement can be returned to the original machine